# Dynamically added <option> elements not visible on UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add  elements dynamically from $.ajax's done() function:

```
$.ajax({
        url: getAllTemplates,
        method: "POST",
        data: form_data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false
    })
        .done(function (data) {
            let templates = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(templates);
            let template_dropdown = $('#template');

            $.each(templates, function (key, value) {
                template_dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr("value", value['name']).text(value['name']));
            });

        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // do something
        });
```

I can see following markup in `console` as well as on `view source` of browser:

[image]

But, it is not getting displayed in actual dropdown in browser:

[image]

Any clue as to what's going wrong here?

Comment: $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh'); please do this

Comment: @Rishab thanks it works. Can you please post this as answer? and then I will accept it.

Comment: Okay sure will add answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are adding dynamically options to the dropdown then you must need to call below function just before adding option

`$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');`

exactly after adding options will update the selectpicker option and make it visible.